# How to update django model automatically on due date?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a task manager app in Django. Tasks have a due date and is_complete status.

```
class Task(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  expire_date = models.DateField()
  is_completed =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

At the time of the task creation, the users should choose the automatically rescheduling option for certain days in case the task is either completed or expired. How can I automatically reschedule the task for the number of days the user has chosen?

Comment: You can use celery to perform your task.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this could be done with a custom django admin command, that gets called through a cron job every day/night? I implemented a similar system that way:

- create one management command (for example, reschedule_expired_tasks)
- create a cron job in linux/your server like `0 0 * * * python /var/www/myapp/manage.py reschedule_expired_tasks`

That way you can check with the command which tasks are expiring today, and just change their new due date to the number of days a user has specified somewhere.

Comment: it could be one way but I am looking for a more direct solution implemented in django.

Comment: alright :) as far as i'm aware django does not provide such functionality, and other solutions to this question often implement more complicated systems like celery. Hopefully someone else can come up with a django specific way.